# How to make this generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constructor, wpfdatagrid

I want to make this class generic class with a constructor of instance `<T>`this is my Class.

```
class Pagenation
{
    public TextBlock PageInformation { get; set; }
    public DataTable dt              { get; set; }
    public ComboBox NumberOfRecords  { get; set; }
    public DataGrid DatagridObject   { get; set; }
    public Button BtnPrev            { get; set; }
    public Button BtnFirst           { get; set; }
    public Button BtnNext            { get; set; }
    public Button BtnLast            { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRecPerPage    { get; set; }

    private int pageIndex = 1;
    private int numberOfRecPerPage;

    public Pagenation(DataGrid UCDatagrid, ComboBox NumberOfRecordsComboBox, int 
                      numOfRecPerPage, TextBlock PageInfo, DataTable Data, 
                      Button Prev, Button First, Button Next, Button Last)
    {
        NumberOfRecordsComboBox.Items.AddRange(new List<string>{ "5", "10", "15", "20" });

        (NumberOfRecords, numberOfRecPerPage, DatagridObject) = 
            (NumberOfRecordsComboBox, numOfRecPerPage, UCDatagrid);

        dt = Data.Copy();

        PageInformation = PageInfo;
        (BtnPrev, BtnFirst, BtnNext, BtnLast) = (Prev, First, Next, Last);
    }
}
```

I want the Pagenation Constructor to Receive an object of Type  `<some project Custom Class>` like the following

```
Pagenation PG = new Pagenation<PartsUC>(this);
```

I made the generic class like this

```
class Pagenation<T>
{
    public Pagenation(T ClassObj)
    {
        NumberOfRecords    = ClassObj.???;  //  want to assign the properties of the ClassObj
        numberOfRecPerPage = ClassObj.???;
        DatagridObject     = ClassObj.???;

        dt = ClassObj.???;

        PageInformation =ClassObj.???;

        (BtnPrev, BtnFirst, BtnNext, BtnLast) = 
            (ClassObj.???, ClassObj.???, ClassObj.???, ClassObj.???);
    }
}
```

I dont know how to  reassign the pagenation Class properties to the properties of the  received `<PartsUC>` instance object

Comment: Why is everything `static`?

Comment: Will the generic be always of type PartsUC or a descendant of it?

Comment: a descendant of it , all of them have the needed properties of pagenation like DataGrid ,.... for example i have PartsUC,EqupmentUC,UsersUC,RequestUC all of them have datagrids.

Comment: @HúsàmShüjáàdiiñ Are thoes class have all same properties? or some are differnt?

Comment: All have the same properties .All of them showing datagrids lists

Comment: You probably don't want all those things to be static. Note that your properties can all be autoimplemented as well. Do your (present and future) self and anyone who will work on your code a favor and stick to a single naming convention. _btnPrev vs _BtnNext, all fields except for numberOfRecsPerPage have a leading underscore...be consistent. You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsut add `where T : PartsUC` after you class name, that will constrain your generic type.

```
class Pagenation<T> where T : PartsUC
{

    public Pagenation(T ClassObj)
    {

        this.NumberOfRecords = ClassObj.NumberOfRecords;
        this.numberOfRecPerPage = ClassObj.numberOfRecPerPage;
        this.DatagridObject = ClassObj.???????;
        //... set your property from PartsUC class
    }
}
```

[Generic where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

**EDIT**
Make an *interface* or *abstract*  be those class contract, then `where: <your interface>`

Your class Implements `IUC` interface, then Encapsulation their own property.

```
public interface IUC{
    Button BtnPrev { get; set;}
    Button BtnFirst{ get; set;}
    Button BtnNext{ get; set;}
    Button BtnLast{ get; set;}
    DataGrid DatagridObject{ get; set;}
    //... all you need property info
}

public class PartsUC : IUC{
    Button BtnPrev { get; set;}
    Button BtnFirst{ get; set;}
    Button BtnNext{ get; set;}
    Button BtnLast{ get; set;}
    DataGrid DatagridObject{ get; set;}
    //... all you need property info
}

public class EqupmentUC : IUC{
    Button BtnPrev { get; set;}
    Button BtnFirst{ get; set;}
    Button BtnNext{ get; set;}
    Button BtnLast{ get; set;}
    DataGrid DatagridObject{ get; set;}
    //... all you need property info
}

public class UsersUC : IUC{
    Button BtnPrev { get; set;}
    Button BtnFirst{ get; set;}
    Button BtnNext{ get; set;}
    Button BtnLast{ get; set;}
    DataGrid DatagridObject{ get; set;}
    //... all you need property info
}


class Pagenation<T> where T : IUC
{

    public Pagenation(T ClassObj)
    {

        this.NumberOfRecords = ClassObj.NumberOfRecords;
        this.numberOfRecPerPage = ClassObj.numberOfRecPerPage;
        //... set your property from PartsUC class
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to tell you that I have more than one class in my project similar to `PartsUC` Class , thats why i want to make it a generic type.

Comment: Make a interface be those class contract , then `where: <your interface>`

Comment: Thank you ,I am new to programming i have read about C# interface class ,I think i got what you mean,i will try it and give you a feedback if that helped.

Comment: I will write a sample for you wait a moment :)

Comment: Thank you so much ,I do really apprecaite your help ^^OK take your time :)

Comment: @HúsàmShüjáàdiiñ I add some sample wish can help you